# Check if an variable is refer to designate object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have an variable assign to an "video" tag, how can I check if this variable is refer to the object of "HTMLVideoElement"

```
var video = document.getElementById('video')
if (video != object HTMLUnknownElement) {
//some code here
}
```

What is the code to replace with object HTMLUnknownElement above?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

typeof is pretty useless, it'll just tell you that it's an object. You'd do better with instanceof: `video instanceof HTMLVideoElement`.

EDIT: Some browsers don't know what an HTMLVideoElement is, so to protect against them throwing an exception here you should check for it: `typeof HTMLVideoElement !== "undefined" && video instanceof HTMLVideoElement`.